# questions about llvm plugin:expression expand,

Tags: llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-ir

expression expand
does llvm have some interface to solve the expression expand problem?
for example:
`b = a + 1`
`c = b + 1`
`d = b * c`
after expression expand, we can know that:
`c = a + 1 + 1`
`d = (a + 1 + 1) * (a + 1)`
i think Reverse Polish notation is useful for this, but i didn't find related description in llvm.

Any help would be appreciated~

Comment: These questions are not related. Please limit each post to a single question. That makes it much easier for other people to search for questions and answers relevant to their needs.

Comment: LLVM's IR language is like RPN in the ways you have in mind. since it's [an SSA language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form). In general, I suggest you learn more about LLVM, so you'll learn the terms it uses. Most of what you mean by 'expression expand' is done by common subexpression elimination in LLVM, for example.